# Inno setup script doesn't run accessruntime after installing .net

Tags: inno-setup

I have some troubles with the installer script
I want to install my app and it needs .net 4.5 to be installed on the host. Also it needs AccessRuntime2007.

I have some troubles because the Accessruntime will not install using the script.
Maybe something wrong with the sequence? who can help me?

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "JazzNotes"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "EMDEE TECH"
#define MyAppURL "www.jazznotes.com"
#define MyAppExeName "JazzNotes.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{2F4E8FD6-6151-45A1-A421-8CA123E312CF}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\license.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\inno output
OutputBaseFilename=Install Jazznotes
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\icons\Itzikgur-My-Seven-Music-Piano-Chello.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom


[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Program Files"; Types: full custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "help"; Description: "Help File";    Types: full
Name: "Net"; Description: ".NET 4.5 Framework";   Types: full
Name: "Acrobat" ; Description: "Acrobat Reader 8"; Types: full
Name: "Access" ; Description: "Access runtime files"; Types: full

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "dependencies\AccessRuntime.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall; AfterInstall: InstallFramework2; Components: Access
Source: "dependencies\AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall; AfterInstall: InstallFramework3; Components: Acrobat
Source: "dependencies\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall; AfterInstall: InstallFramework; Check: FrameworkIsNotInstalled ;Components: Net



Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\JazzNotes.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion      ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\AxInterop.WMPLib.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion    ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion  ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\Interop.WMPLib.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion  ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\JazzNotes.exe.config"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\NAudio.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion  ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\bin\x86\Release\UltraID3Lib.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion  ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion     ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion    ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Deployment.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Design.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion    ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion     ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Drawing.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion    ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion    ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion      ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.XML.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion      ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion    ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\stdole.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion       ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\LTYPE.TTF"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion      ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\LTYPEB.TTF"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion      ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\LTYPEBO.TTF"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\MusiCAT\LTYPEO.TTF"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion   ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\jingle.wav"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion     ; Components: program
Source: "C:\Users\donnersm\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MusiCAT\musica.accdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion    ; Components: program
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Code]
function FrameworkIsNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.5');
end;

procedure InstallFramework;
var
  StatusText: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing .NET framework...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe'), '/q /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
       // you can interact with the user that the installation failed
       MsgBox('.NET installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
         mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end;

procedure InstallFramework2;
var
  StatusText: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing Access Runtime files...';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AccessRuntime.exe'), '/q /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
       // you can interact with the user that the installation failed
       MsgBox('Access Runtime installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
         mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end;


procedure InstallFramework3;
var
  StatusText: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  StatusText := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing Acrobar Reader';
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstMarquee;
  try
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe'), '/q /noreboot', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
       // you can interact with the user that the installation failed
       MsgBox('Acrobat installation failed with code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) + '.',
         mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := StatusText;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style := npbstNormal;
  end;
end;






[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: If the AccessRuntime needs .NET (I do not know, but your question title suggests that), then you have to install it after the .NET framework. You install it first now. Also, you should tell us, why the installation fails. We won't guess for you. Just remove `/q` switch and you will see what's wrong. -1 until you give us some sensible details.

Comment: OK, I removed the /q and i am compiling...I will run it and give the feedback. In regards to the app...My application needs both Access runtime libary, the .net 4.5 runtime library and the acrobat reader...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin ! Your advise in removing the /q helped! Turns out that the accessruntime.exe does not allow the /noreboot....i changed it to /norestart... and it worked!